# Hi guys i want to automate gmail OTP Verification password using selenium Automation Utility

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-java

This is the error i received

[image: 1]

I expect Gmail otp automation using automation utilities
. but some error are shown like EmailUtils refers to the missing type Store

Comment: please share the code you tried and let see what is the problem

Comment: that problem shorted i add some dependencies then that one is cleared but currently i new issues came . i need proper guidence to automate otp authentication using selenium java webdriver .